# Can someone please tell me what the letters TSE stand for after an attny name?

Tags: legal-terms, trusts-and-estates

What do the letter's TSE stand for at the end of an attny name?

Comment: Where is this attorney?

Comment: Is there any possibility this might be an actual family name, probably Chinese, and maybe the name of the firm?

Comment: Likely just surname, like this one: https://www.lawsociety.org.nz/register/nathan-jack-tse/

Answer (score 1):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

These have no special legal meaning in Canada. There is no accreditation with this initialism that is legally relevant in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Tse is a common Chinese family name which is shared by a great many lawyers. But if the lawyer uses a non-Chinese given name and middle name, it can look like an honorific rather than a surname, if you aren't aware that Tse can be a surname.

The letters TSE are not honorifics or a professional certification in any legal jurisdiction in the world that I have been able to identify with a moderately in depth search.

Answer (score 1):

In some locales, particularly in Europe, the family name is written in all caps, like "Mr. Given FAMILY". Some cultures put the family name first, like "Dr. FAMILY Given". The convention makes it clear which is which, and also helps when a [name part consists of multiple words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs).

Therefore, a name written like "John Smith TSE" would indicate a first name of John, a middle name of Smith, and a last/family name of Tse.